# How to i solve this error -heroku CLI error when trying to deploy appliaction

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, continuous-integration

Application error when i try to access the app from the url. this is the error from the logs

`2018-11-14T10:57:51.683297+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! easy-shop@0.0.0 start:`ng serve
`2018-11-14T10:57:51.683411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-11-14T10:57:51.683785+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-11-14T10:57:51.683972+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the easy-shop@0.0.0 start script.
2018-11-14T10:57:51.684145+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-11-14T10:57:51.693817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-11-14T10:57:51.694093+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-11-14T10:57:51.694272+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-11-14T10_57_51_686Z-debug.log
2018-11-14T10:57:51.753202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-11-14T10:57:51.744306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1`

Help me out

Answer (score 0):

The ENOENT error suggests the file doesnt exists on Heroku.
This can happen if you added it to your .gitignore or generally haven't checked it into git.